# Is atomicity still a concern in register/register instructions?

Tags: multithreading, atomic

**Atomicity** is a concern when multiple threads access a shared variable in memory.
Atomic instructions make sure multiple operations are done as a whole (either fully done or not done at all).

Now when dealing with instructions that don't access memory, and say only `add` two registers, is atomicity still a concern?

Comment: Not on any ISA that I'm aware of.  For a start, one thread / core can't see another one's registers.

Comment: However, things might potentially get *a bit interesting* in a pipelined architecture if there was the possibility that (say) an integer divide by zero or segfault could cause a hardware trap.  If the hardware supported out-of-order instruction execution, it might not be possible to be certain if certain register to register operations had happened or not.  (But this is hypothetical ... unless we are talking about a particular ISA.)